# ListView onItemClickListener works on part of custom row only

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a custom `ListView` where each row consists of 3 items, a `TextView` (title), an `ImageView` (placeholder icon), and another `TextView` (content text). I have an `OnItemLongClickListener` set on the `ListView` and it is supposed to be that when a user clicks on the item in the `ListView` (which should be the entire row of 3 items all together as one), then a dialog comes up giving them the option to delete the whole item, which would then delete all 3 parts of that single list item.

But long clicking on the title view and the image do not trigger the listener. Only if the content `TextView` is long clicked, does the dialog box come up, which then deletes all 3, but clicking anywhere in the row **should** do that. However it doesn't. I need to find a solution because the user will not know to only click on the content `TextView`, they should be able to click anywhere.

I have looked on here to find a solution, and have tried adding these lines, but nothing has worked:

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` added to my `ListView`'s `LinearLayout`.

`android:clickable="false"` to my `ImageView`.

`android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to both `TextView`s.

I don't have anything else to try. Any ideas?

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I added extra lines, like @Amrit suggested (code in his answer), the whole area when long clicked does now bring up the dialog box, but it creates this strange tint on the area I click, but only if I click the title `TextView` or the `ImageView` area. Oddly, that 2nd `TextView` still looks good and produces the dialog box as it should. Not sure how to get rid of this misaligned tint though:

[image]

**TextTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.texttab;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class TextTab extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListViewPoemAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    String[] allSDCardFiles = null;
    StringBuilder text;
    PoemListItem wordsFromFile;
    File[] files;
    PoemListItem sampleItem;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_tab, container, false);
        adapter = new ListViewPoemAdapter(getActivity(), poems);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter.getCount() == 0) {
            // load contents of SD card
            loadSDCard();
        }

        setupListViewListener();

        return v;

    }

    private void loadSDCard(){

        try {
            // gets directory CuteWords from sd card
            File cuteWordsDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "/Cute Words");

            if (!cuteWordsDir.exists()){
                cuteWordsDir.mkdir();
            }

            if (cuteWordsDir.isDirectory()) {
                // lists all files in CuteWords, loads in Files[] array
                files = cuteWordsDir.listFiles();

                for (File singleFile : files) {
                    //Read text from file, put each line into StringBuilder
                    text = new StringBuilder();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(singleFile));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');

                        // get full file name with ext. and text in file
                        wordsFromFile = new PoemListItem(singleFile.getName(), text.toString());

                        adapter.add(wordsFromFile);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            // get number of files in CuteWords directory
            allSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];

            // create a blank String version of PoemListItem
            sampleItem = new PoemListItem(" ", " ");

            // add the default icon/lines remaining to ArrayList (through adapter),
            // if less than 9 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (9 - allSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                adapter.add(sampleItem);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    // so you can edit any of the list items
    private void setupListViewListener() {

        // to delete a list item
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                                        final int pos, long id) {


                if (adapter.getItem(pos) != sampleItem) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle("Delete")
                            .setMessage("Delete these cute words?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // delete from ArrayList first
                                    poems.remove(pos);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    // get file name then delete it
                                    String name = files[pos].getName();
                                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                            "/Documents/Cute Words/" + name);
                                    file.delete();

                                    // clear list and adapter
                                    poems.clear();
                                    adapter.clear();
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    // after each item delete, must refresh load with new arrangement
                                    loadSDCard();

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    // do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();

                    }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**ListViewPoemAdapter**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.texttab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class ListViewPoemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PoemListItem> {

    private TextView poemText;
    private TextView poemTitle;
    private ImageView poemPlaceholder;


    public ListViewPoemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems) {
        super(context, 0, poems);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        PoemListItem poemListItem = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.text_listview_row, parent, false);
        }

        poemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        poemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        poemPlaceholder = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_placeholder_poem);

        poemText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                              InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE |
                              InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

        poemText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        poemPlaceholder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_poem_placeholder);
        poemPlaceholder.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        poemPlaceholder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150));

        poemTitle.setText(poemListItem.getTitle());
        poemText.setText(poemListItem.getPoem());

        return convertView;

    }


}
```

**text_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="#2198bb">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_list_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        android:divider="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**text_listview_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/icon_placeholder_poem"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:ellipsize="start"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:hint="Quote or poem, here."
        android:ellipsize="start"/>

    <!--Line in-between the rows-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#7e8287"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I swear, some people down vote and don't even read my post. If they had, and actually searched Stack, they would find that NONE of the long click listener posts address my situation. I'm not the only one with this issue either, I found about 2 or 3 identical ones where they had NO answer. Just wanted people to know that, so they take the time to actually consider all of this before carelessly down voting. If you down vote for another reason, PLEASE write it in the comments. I always strive for well-researched, succinct questions, before I ask them.

Comment: Hi again. I can't believe you still have this annoying problem and SO tech cannot help. Anyway I think I have a good answer for you, tho it's rather late.

Comment: I think you said you tried OnItemLongClickListener on the Listview object, and it did not worked. I think this is a bug in Android. I believe setting android:longClickable="true" in all the UI elements in a layout, would have worked. Of course you still have to add code to the listener but that's just a little nuisance. I never had your issue before only because my TextView is quite long/wide in the Listview. So the user will instinctively press on the long text. If you think this is the best/correct answer, pls post another question to this, and notify me.

Comment: Hi @TheOriginalAndroid, I was wondering if you might be available for an offline chat somehow, I was looking for a mentor of sorts, and wanted to see if you might be interested. I could explain more details soon. :)

Comment: Hi Noni, What's up these days? I have good memories of you and you're smart. Anyway, how about a virtual meeting around 10 pm, we can invite a chat in this webpage/forum.  Do you have a LinkedIn account for us to connect?  I am eager to hear what you have to say.

Comment: Well, I just sent you an invite. I think I found you on LInkedIn, certainly your photo here looks different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set all child views inside listView items to not focusable or clickable.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

If it is not enough try setting

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants
```

to text_listview_row.xml linearlayout &

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

to textview's inside text_listview_row.xml

**UPDATE**

Actually all that I needed was that one line `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but inside of my `LinearLayout` parent of the **text_listiew_row.xml** (not needed in **text_tab.xml**). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Amrit, this almost works, excepts one small flaw... the whole area is now clickable, but when I click, the entire row changes in tint, except it's misaligned. I cannot get a screen shot of this, because it is only temporary on the click (my guess is it's a default Android OS thing)... but is there a way to have it align properly on the list item? It is just about `20dp` below where it should be.

Comment: Actually upon further testing, exactly the title `TextView` and the `ImageView` are the ones with the weird "tint animation" on them. If I click on the content `TextView`, it does not appear.

Comment: No idea about this weird "tint animation" which you have mentioned, ok let me test it once, will get back to you if I found any solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to explain. I know when I downloaded the API 22 update, my whole phone started doing this when I clicked on anything. It does like a slightly darker tint over the click area, then shows a slight "drop in a pool ripple", right where you click. Weird I know, lol. Well, I will keep testing too, thanks. :)

Comment: So, it only get started after you downloaded API 22 update ? And it will be good if you will be able to post some snapshot of this darker tint or "drop in pool ripple".. whatever you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, my entire app suddenly has a little animation wherever I click. But the odd part is it does not happen when I click the `TextView` with content. I will see if I can post a video(?) Or try to take a photo with my other phone at the right moment.

Comment: Amrit, I added a photo of the tint box. I could not capture the animation part, but this gives you a basic idea. See how it is misaligned... strange.

Comment: Oh wait... maybe that is because of the padding, and other things I have set... I will experiment and let you know. This might be the right solution after all.

Comment: In your 1st comment you've mentioned that tint is just about "20dp" below where it should be, I haven't tested it but try removing "android:paddingBottom="20dp"" from root linearlayout & test it again if it is proper aligned.

Comment: Totally got it to work! Yeah, that was it. I just used `android:divider="#7e8287"` and `android:dividerHeight="4px"` in my parent `LinearLayout` in **text_tab.xml** and deleted that `View` tag which manually made a line. I also played around with the code you gave me, some of it was not needed so I will post the minimum needed. But thanks so much, can't thank you enough!

Comment: I still get the animation only on the `TextView` title area and the `ImageView` area (and not on the `TextView` content area), but I can live with that. ;)

Comment: Most Welcome..!! & feel free to edit/update my answer (with the minimum code which worked for you) so that it will be useful to other's also :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the below tag fro your views inside list item view xml (**text_listview_row.xml**)

```
android:focusable="false"
```

so that list item click will work always perfectly

Comment: Thanks, do you mean the parent `LinearLayout` of that file?

Comment: Okay, I just tried it and still have the same problem. Only a certain area (the content text) of the `ListView` row accepts the long lick.

Comment: try adding android:focusable="false" for all other child layouts not for parent layout

Comment: I put it on both `LinearLayout`s and all the other views in **text_listview_row.xml** and still nothing helped. Is there any other place that can go?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
if (adapter.getItem(pos) != sampleItem) {
```

Add log before to verify that method was invoked successfully.

```
Log.d("TextTab", "onItemLongClick");
if (adapter.getItem(pos) != sampleItem) {
    ...
```

Comment: I thought that too, then I removed the conditional, and it still happened. The `sampleItem` is a different `PoemListItem` object as well, so disabling that should still allow the other items to delete entirely. I added it in general so you cannot delete the placeholders (an empty string). Although I could try your log suggestion, but what are you looking for with "onItemLongClick", what should I put there? Sorry, did not understand.

Comment: The image doesn't show it, but if your list is not completely full, then just the icon and 2 empty `String`s show, separated by those grey lines. Basically what you see, except all text removed. (Just to explain the conditional further).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your case, but I had similar problem with click on a custom layout item. After a hour of looking for solution a found out that I set android:inputType to TextView inside my layout file which was blocking onClick() listener
(no idea why)

Don't use android:inputType with TextView.

It worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Asked by many, The TextViews in list should not have width match parent.

Even if you set the "Focusable" to false it wont work.
Set the TextView Width to wrap_content

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemchild"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
```